# ¿Cómo generar página estática para indexar en buscador de google en app angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Estoy desarrollando un **webApp** con **angularjs**, y quisiera que mi página de inicio, donde muestro información de la app en sí y su **login/register**, pueda ser indexada en los buscadores de google. Estuve viendo **angular universal**, pero genera los archivos estáticos de todas las rutas principales, y yo solo deseo hacerla en una.

¿Que otra alternativa puede ser?

Podría generar otro servidor para mostrar esta página con archivos estáticos con **handlebar** o alguno más, pero ya tengo 2 servidores, uno para la app y otro para la api que sirve el contenido a esta app.

Comment: Agrega tu código que hayas intentando

Comment: Hasta ahora solo el default de angular universal

Comment: Estás usando AngularJS o Angular 2 (o superiores)? En Angular deberías poder añadir la información meta de tu página en el archivo index.html